# how to extract the text between " " in Python

Tags: python

For instance, how there is a string `a`, which is defined as

```
a = "\"hello\""
```

how to use `re` extract the text `hello`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
m = re.search('"([^"]*)"', a)
m.group(1)
```

The `[^"]*` says that there must be no `"` inside the string.

That is important for cases like:

```
"a" bcd "e"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
re.search('"(.*)"', "\"hello\"").group(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can also be solved with [shlex](http://docs.python.org/library/shlex.html).split(), which will split a string in the same way that the Unix shell splits the command line parameters. In other words, it will respect quotes.  Depending on what you are ultimately trying to do, it may be safer and more appropriate.